# Почему замещаются и дублируются строчки при сортировке в гугл таблицах?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-spreadsheet

[image: Таблица]

Есть таблица, вверху форма внесения заказа, внизу заказы. На самих заказах стоит защита и заказы вносятся из формы по триггеру "при редактировании". Когда заказов достаточно много, около 25-30, может случиться либо замена наложение заказов друг на друга при сортировке, либо дублирование, такое случается крайне редко, но мне все же нужно устранить данную проблему и я не могу понять в чем причина.

```js
function vnestizakaz() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet()
  var as = ss.getActiveSheet()
  if (as.getRange(3, 14).isChecked() === true){
  var vvod = as.getRange(2, 1, 1, 10).getValues()
  var itog = 0
  var raschet = as.getRange(2, 12).getValue()
  var lr = as.getLastRow()
  var lc = as.getLastColumn()
    var clear = as.getRange(2, 3, 1, 7).clear({formatOnly: false, contentsOnly: true}) 
    var clear2 = as.getRange(2, 12).clear({formatOnly: false, contentsOnly: true}) 
    if(raschet != ""){
   as.getRange(lr+1, 1, 1, 10).setValues(vvod)
   as.getRange(lr+1, 11).setFormulaR1C1("=R[0]C[-2] + R[0]C[-1]")
   as.getRange(lr+1, 12).setValue(raschet)
   as.getRange(lr+1, 13).setValue("0")
   as.getRange('A7:P').sort([{column: 2, ascending: true}]); 
      }
   as.getRange(3, 14).uncheck()
  }
}
```

Comment: Попробуйте перед получением данных про посл. заполненные строки/столбцы ( `getLastRow` / `getLastColumn` ) использовать `SpreadsheetApp.flush()`

Comment: А что делает flush? Почитал в справочнике, не очень понял

Comment: Как написано, применяет ожидающие изменения. То есть если вы что-то делаете с таблицей кодом - то эти изменения сначала накапливаются - а потом скопом делаются. Как-то так.

Comment: `SpreadsheetApp.flush()
  var lr = as.getLastRow()
  var lc = as.getLastColumn()`
Сделал вот так, изменений не было

Comment: Попробуйте тогда в коде логгировать все действия. Тогда, когда произойдет проблема - вы будете знать на каком этапе и с какими данными